# why i++ is acting like thread safe operation when Console.WriteLine is on the next line

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I was reading a book about C# when reached a statement that claims that the following code will produce 20000 increments to the shared **count** variable and the final value of **count** will be 20000.
When I run it, ii always prints 20000. As far as I remember count++ is not thread safe operation and when Console.WriteLine is removed the printed result is as expected - not 20000 in all cases.
Can someone explain why count has 20000 as a final value in this case. and why count++ acts as a thread safe operation.

```
    private static void testTask()
    {
        Task t1 = new Task(() =>
          {
              for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
              {
                  count++;
                  Console.WriteLine("Thread 1 - {0}", count);
              }
          }
       );

        Task t2 = new Task(() =>
         {
             for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
             {
                 count++;
                 Console.WriteLine("Thread 2 - {0}", count);
             }
         }
      );
        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();
        Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);
        Console.WriteLine("Count - {0}", count);
    }
```

Comment: Wrap the call to `testTask` in another loop, remove the `Console.WriteLine` after `count++` and you will see the value isn't always 20000.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It isn't actually making it safe, you are just affecting the timing reducing the odds of seeing the effects. Executing `i++` takes a fraction of the time `Console.Write` takes, so you are increasing the odds that the `i++` in one thread will be executed during a `Console.Write` in the other. Run it enough times and you'll probably find the same behavior.

---

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            testTask();
        }

        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void testTask()
    {
        int count = 0;

        Task t1 = new Task(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                count++;
                //Console.WriteLine("Thread 1 - {0}", count);
            }
        }
       );

        Task t2 = new Task(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                count++;
                //Console.WriteLine("Thread 2 - {0}", count);
            }
        }
      );
        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();
        Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);
        Console.WriteLine("Count - {0}", count);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 I also added complete code to demonstrate this, sometimes the value is as low as 10000.

Comment: without Console.WriteLine the behavior is as expected but putting back Console.WriteLine and this code always gives the same result - that was kind a strange for me. Maybe I just didn't hit the 1% case.

Comment: Console.WriteLine is also a synchronized operation, which "helps" to make it less likely to witness the side effect.